# Is there a way to identify if Jenkins element got modified thought inspect in chrome?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, web-inspector

I have Jenkins job with Active Choices Parameter. Is there a way to identify if its value was modified thought web inspector?

Comment: you can inspect the HTML/JS code or use the "network" tab to monitor requests in the web inspector to check if Jenkins element like Active Choices Parameter has been modified.

Comment: I meant if I can to it from the jenkins job...

Comment: try using plugins like "Config File Provider" and "Audit Trail".

Comment: Can you provide more details? how they can help me?